# How can I fill figure between y = x^3, x= -1, x=1 and y = 0?

Tags: filling

I am trying filling between of lines: $ y = x^3$, $y=0$, $x=-1$, and $x=1$. I tried.

```
Plot[{x^3, 0}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {LightBlue, White}}}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

and got
[image]

How can I get fill graph with x from 0 to 1?

Comment: Maybe change `White` to something you can see ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.

Comment: Plotting a constant zero function is not necessary.  `Filling -> { 1 -> {Axis, LightBlue} }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[x^3, {x, -1, 1},
  Filling -> {1 -> 0}, 
  PlotStyle -> None, 
  FillingStyle -> LightBlue]
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, `Filling -> Axis`

Comment: @BobHanlon I chose to fill to 0 because the AxesOrigin may not always be `{0,0}`.